# How to force the linker to treat an archive file like many object files?

Tags: archive, ld

In my homemade build system, I create many `.a` files. I then want to link these into one final image.

The issue is that `ld` naturally assumes these are libraries, and therefore links none of the symbols in, producing an empty image as output.

Can I force `ld` to treat these as groups of object files?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me only answer is: you can't  put the `main` in a library!

If you keep main as object file, then it will pull the threads of the whole program, and even if the rest of it is in `.a` files it should link just fine.